# A property about quasi-primary modules

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

It is a fact that any discrete valuation domain $R$ has the property "P" that any proper submodule $N$ of any $R$-module $M$ is quasi-primary, in the sense that $\operatorname{rad}(N:M)$ is a prime ideal of $R$, where $(N:M)=\{r\in R : rM⊆N\}$. My conjecture is

> Krull dimension of $R$ equal to zero is equivalent to that $R$ has property "P".

It is easy to see that any vector space, or $\mathbb Q$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module has "P".

Is there anybody helping me in this regard? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any valuation domain $R$ satisfies the condition "P".

> If $I$ is a proper ideal of a valuation domain $R$, then $\sqrt I$ is a prime ideal.

Let $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\in\sqrt I$. Then there is $n\ge 1$ such that $(ab)^n\in I$. If $a\mid b$ write $b=ax$ and note that $b^{2n}\in I$, so $b\in\sqrt I$.

The conclusion: it is not possible to bound the Krull dimension of rings with the property "P".

Comment: Thanks. I edited the statement of the problem to the effect that any "valuation domain" has "P" by reference to "On Quasi-Primary Submodules" Proposition 2.6, S.Atani, and A.Darani, Chiang Mai J. Sci. 2006; 33(3) : 249-254. Is the conjecture yet in place?

Comment: @karparvar First of all, your edit makes my answer to look somehow obsolete, and I had to roll it back. About your claim: it is wrong in both directions! If $\dim R=0$ then take an artinian non-local ring, $M=R$ and $N=m_1\cap m_2$ where $m_i$ are maximal ideals, and notice that $\sqrt{N:M}$ is not prime. If $R$ has property "P" then $\dim R$ can be any positive integer as my answer shows (the valuation domains can have any dimension, except zero, of course).